# trouble using data from local JSON file

Tags: polymer

I'm building a simple list app in Polymer but am having trouble moving my data objects from within an element to a separate JSON file using iron-ajax.

Here's my code:

```
<dom-module id="my-view">

  <template>
    <div class="content">
      <create-form watchlist="{{watchlist}}"></create-form>
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{watchlist}}" as="watchitems">
          <my-items watchitems="{{watchitems}}"></my-items>
      </template>
    </div>

    <iron-ajax
      auto
      url="/data/watchlist.json"
      params='{}'
      handle-as="json"
      on-response="gotList"
      debounce-duration="300"></iron-ajax>

  </template>

  <script>

Polymer({
  is: 'my-view',

  properties: {
    watchlist: {
      type: Array
    }
  },
  gotList: function(event, ironRequest) {
    this.watchlist = ironRequest.response;
  },
  ready: function() {
    this.watchlist = [];
  }
});
```

In the .my-items element, I'm declaring the object's properties.

From my understanding, the json data should be used in the empty array space in the Ready: function.  However, this is not happening.

When I manually fill in data in the Ready: array, it works, so that part of the data binding appears to be okay.  Seems that the JSON data is not entering correctly.

Comment: Why did you ask the same question twice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35857552/iron-ajax-not-working-with-local-json-file

Answer (score 0):

this.watchlist = []; assigns a blank list to watchlist. Your gotlist function is the one that assigns the json to watchlist.

Comment: makes sense.  How does that happen?  Simply removing the  this.watchlist = [] doesn't fix the issue.  I need to declare it somehow, right?