# iron-ajax not working with local json file?

Tags: polymer

In my polymer app, pulling in json data via iron-ajax element works fine, but I can't get it to work with my local json file.  I've hosted the app on firebase, but still no luck.

This doesn't work:

```
<iron-ajax
      auto
      url="data/watchlist.json"
      last-response="{{data}}"
      handle-as="json">
</iron-ajax>
```

But, this does works:

```
<iron-ajax
      auto
      url="http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/"
      last-response="{{data}}"
      handle-as="json">
</iron-ajax>
```

What am I doing wrong?  Can't tell if I'm doing something wrong with polymer or with ajax/json calls.

Comment: What does the developer console / Firebug say when you load the site? To debug this request, you could try adding an "on-response" / "on-error" handler to the iron-ajax element and add a breakpoint there.

Comment: Hey, did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

That is probably a browser limitation for security purposes. 
Check the browser console you probably get an error that tells you why Chrome is blocking the request.
Start up a server that serves this file and fetch it from there. You need to enable CORS support on the server if it is a different one than where you load `index.html` from.